# Is there a simple way to change this date format into dateline format?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have this date format (thousands in this form).

```
time_from = '2020-11-28T06:00:00-06:00'
time_to = '2020-11-28T09:00:00-06:00'
```

And I want it to transform them into datetime format so I can compute the total # of seconds between the times quickly (see below). I'm thinking a for loop where I go through each hour/day of the string and save them in a list. But, wondering if there's an easier way?

```
import datetime as dt

a = dt.datetime(2013,12,30,23,59,59)
b = dt.datetime(2013,12,31,23,59,59)

(b-a).total_seconds()
```

Comment: I didn't understand what difficulty you were facing. Have you looked up how to parse this date format using `strptime` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)?

Comment: do you have those 1000s of time_from/time_to in a dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fromisoformat` to do this. Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat).

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-11-28T06:00:00-06:00')
end = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-11-28T09:00:00-06:00')
(end-start).total_seconds()
```